# Rx Java 2: How to wrap a callback?

Tags: java, android, callback, rx-java2

I have this code to wrap a callback in Rx Java 1 and it compiles fine , but now that I have switched to RX Java 2 it does not compile...what is the equivalent in Rx Java 2?

```
return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(AsyncEmitter<Integer> emitter) {

                transObs.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                        if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED)
                            emitter.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                        emitter.onError(ex);
                    }
                });

                emitter.setCancellation(new AsyncEmitter.Cancellable() {
                    @Override
                    public void cancel() throws Exception {

                        transObs.cleanTransferListener();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```

UPDATE:

I came up with this, but Do you have to deal with backpressure since its an oncreate call?

```
 return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<DigitsUser>>() {

        @Override
        public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<List<DigitsUser>> emitter) throws Exception {

            mDigitFriends.findFriends((gotEm, users) -> {
                emitter.onNext(users);
            });

            emitter.setCancellable(() -> {
                emitter.onNext(null);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: what do yo man but no compiled? you need to be more specific, what is the error, what have you try, etc. as for your question it's probably needs to be what is the equivalent to fromEmitter() in RxJava2 , and the answer is create()

Comment: 1) You don't even call `emitter.onNext` anywhere, no wonder there is no data. 2) You left off the cancellation part. 3) If you need an Observable, use an Observable!

Comment: I updated my potential solution

Answer (score 6):

If you're worried about backpressure you should use the Flowable class.  Here's a quote from the [RxJava2 Wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0):

> Practically, the 1.x fromEmitter (formerly fromAsync) has been renamed
>   to Flowable.create.

Here is your example using the Flowable class:

```
 return Flowable.create(new FlowableEmitter<List<DigitsUser>>() {

        @Override
        public void subscribe(final FlowableEmitter<List<DigitsUser>> emitter) throws Exception {

            mDigitFriends.findFriends((gotEm, users) -> {
                emitter.onNext(users);
            });

            emitter.setCancellable(() -> {
                emitter.onNext(null);
            });
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
```

Comment: In RxJava 2 it is not allowed to emit null, this code will simply crash